# Commutator subgroup of $B_n (K) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $B_n(K)$ be the set of upper unit triangular matrices with entries of a field $K$. In lecture we were told that the commutator of $B_n(K)$ (written as $[x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for $x,y \in B_n(K)$ and $[B_n, B_n]=B_n'$) is the set of unit upper triangular matrices such that all the elements of the form $a_{i,i+1}$ are equal to zero. Further more we obtain, that for $B_n''= [B_n',B_n']$ all Elements $a_{i,i+1}$ and $a_{i,i+2}$ are zero and through induction obtain that $B_n^{(n)} = id$.

I do not know how to prove it, mainly because I am failing to determine the inverse of an arbitrary unit upper triangular matrix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can start by looking at the subset of the [Shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping). Those have an easy-to-compute inverse and generate the upper unit triangular matrices.

Comment: Calculate the commutators of the matrices with a single entry $1$ off the main diagonal and all other non-diagonal matrices $0$. That is straightforward, and those commutators are enough to geenrate the whole commutator subgroup.  You can prove that  by showing that the associated quotient group is abelian.

Comment: Thanks for the tipps